# How to rotate single chevron on accordion in vue?

Tags: vue.js, drop-down-menu

I am using vue chevron in accordion inside for loop. When I am clicking a single dropdown, all other chevrons are rotating. How to rotate the specific chevron for the clicked dropdown in vue ? I am using vue chevron package from https://ispal.github.io/vue-chevron/ . My dropdown looks like this -

[image: dropdown]

**My vue code:**

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                <div
                  v-for="(data, index) in topicList"
                  :key="index"
                  class="card"
                >
                  <div class="card_header" id="headingOne">
                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                      <div
                        class="btn btn-topic example text-left collapsed"
                        @click="toggle"
                        type="button"
                        data-toggle="collapse"
                        :data-target="'#collapseOne' + index"
                        aria-expanded="true"
                        aria-controls="collapseOne"
                      >
                        <vue-chevron
                          :point-down="pointDown"
                          :duration="duration"
                          :thickness="thickness"
                          :angle="angle"
                          :round-edges="roundEdges"
                        />
                        {{ data.title }}
                      </div>
                    </h2>
                  </div>

                  <div
                    :id="'collapseOne' + index"
                    class="collapse"
                    aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                    data-parent="#accordionExample"
                  >
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <ul
                        v-for="(data, index) in topicList[index].lessons"
                        :key="index"
                        @click="getContent(data.lessonId)"
                        class="list-group py-1"
                      >
                        <li class="list-group-item list-style">
                          {{ data.title }}
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

<script>
   import VueChevron from "vue-chevron"
export default{
  components:{ VueChevron }
  data(){
    return{
      pointDown: false,
      thickness: 8,
      duration: 500,
      angle: 40,
      roundEdges: true,
      easing: function n(t) {
        return t;
    }
  }

methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.pointDown = !this.pointDown;
    },
}
}
```

```
courseAccess() {
      this.$axios
        .get(this.$api + "api/v1/courses/" + this.courseId, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("_utoken"),
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          // this.topicList = response.data.data.topics.map((element) => {
          //   return { ...element, pointDown: true };
          // });
          this.topicList = response.data.data.topics
          this.firstTopic = response.data.data.topics[0].lessons[0].lessonId;
          this.getFirstContent(this.firstTopic);
          this.loadTopics = true;
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

All vue-chevron are binding there point-down prop to the same boolean. You could try to use an array of boolean instead and change your toggle method.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                <div
                  v-for="(data, index) in topicList"
                  :key="index"
                  class="card"
                >
                  <div class="card_header" id="headingOne">
                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                      <div
                        class="btn btn-topic example text-left collapsed"
                        @click="toggle(index)"
                        type="button"
                        data-toggle="collapse"
                        :data-target="'#collapseOne' + index"
                        aria-expanded="true"
                        aria-controls="collapseOne"
                      >
                        <vue-chevron
                          :point-down="pointDown[index]"
                          :duration="duration"
                          :thickness="thickness"
                          :angle="angle"
                          :round-edges="roundEdges"
                        />
                        {{ data.title }}
                      </div>
                    </h2>
                  </div>

                  <div
                    :id="'collapseOne' + index"
                    class="collapse"
                    aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                    data-parent="#accordionExample"
                  >
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <ul
                        v-for="(data, index) in topicList[index].lessons"
                        :key="index"
                        @click="getContent(data.lessonId)"
                        class="list-group py-1"
                      >
                        <li class="list-group-item list-style">
                          {{ data.title }}
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

<script>
   import VueChevron from "vue-chevron"
export default{
  components:{ VueChevron }
  data(){
    return{
      pointDown: [],
      thickness: 8,
      duration: 500,
      angle: 40,
      roundEdges: true,
      easing: function n(t) {
        return t;
    }
  }

methods: {
    toggle(index) {
      this.pointDown[index] = !this.pointDown[index];
    },
}
}
```

### EDIT

The problem discussed in the comments could be caused by reactivity issues. To solve these we are trying to initialize `pointDown` with an array of the correct size.

```js
courseAccess() {
      this.$axios
        .get(this.$api + "api/v1/courses/" + this.courseId, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("_utoken"),
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          // this.topicList = response.data.data.topics.map((element) => {
          //   return { ...element, pointDown: true };
          // });
          this.topicList = response.data.data.topics;
          this.pointDown = new Array(this.topicList.length).fill(false);
          this.firstTopic = response.data.data.topics[0].lessons[0].lessonId;
          this.getFirstContent(this.firstTopic);
          this.loadTopics = true;
        });
    },
```

Comment: Did as you said. Now they are not rotating anymore.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the browsers console? If you have the vue.js devtools for you browser you could also take a look at the value of pointDown.

Comment: I havent used vue devtools before. And there is no error in console.

Comment: Could it be that you have missed the change in data? `pointDown: [],`

Comment: Yes I have declared pointDown: []  inside data->return.

Comment: I haven't seen in your source code where `topicList` is declared or initialized/loaded. Could you edit your question and add this part?

Comment: Yes. I have added the code at the end of my post. Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243112/discussion-between-jkoch-and-alprazolam).